# ng-container => blank page bug in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

In order to have a clean and DRY ionic project, I just wanted my navbar code to be written in one place, instead of writing the whole HTML in every Ionic page.

For this purpose, I created an Angular component (not an Ionic page) named `navbar`, and I inject it in my pages. To keep a clean layout with no additional stuff in the DOM, I created a component with the brackets notation, like this:

```
@Component({
  // brackets let the selector be used as a property instead of a component
  selector: '[navbar]',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.html',
})
export class NavbarComponent {

  @Input() title: string = 'default title';
  constructor() {}

}
```

Then I try to inject the component in the pages like this:

```
<ng-container navbar title="My good title"></ng-container>
```

The purpose is to not create any additional node in the DOM to keep clean layout.
But, this DOES NOT WORK, as I get a blank page with no particular error in console.

As a comparison,

```
<div navbar title="My good title"></div>
```

works, but my layout is broken (ion content starts from the very top of my page, beeing hidden by navbar)

Any idea? Thanks.

// navbar.html code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="ios-menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons margin-horizontal end>
      <img class="logo-navbar" src="../../assets/imgs/logo-hudi-noir-noborder.png">
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2
  Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
 @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Comment: Are you importing the component module into ionic page module?

Comment: you need to post the code to your root module. Also, installing the Augury chrome extension will help you debug the issue. I know it has helped me when getting the white screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the `navbar` attribute to the `ion-header` element:

```
<ion-header navbar title="My good title"></ion-header>
```

and define the `NavbarComponent` as the content of that element:

```
<ion-navbar>
  <button ion-button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="ios-menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
  <ion-buttons margin-horizontal end>
    <img class="logo-navbar" src="../../assets/imgs/logo-hudi-noir-noborder.png">
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lpvfcj) for a demo.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot. May I ask you to elaborate about why my solution did not work first? Thanks again.

Comment: When setting the `navbar` attribute on an element, it appears that the element becomes the parent of the `NavbarComponent` content. Since `ng-container` is not rendered at all in the HTML ouput, the component ends up with no parent. By the way, maybe the title of the question could be changed to something like "Reusable Ionic navbar component"